# Issue with Postgres on windows 10

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, web, backend

I have installed PostgreSQL 13 on windows 10
When I tried to run this command:
`$ which Postgres` on Git Bash, It returns `which: no Postgres in (/c/Users*ahmedeid/......`
Could you help me solve the issue?

Comment: What should I use?

Comment: could you please try `which psql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your PostgreSQL installation's `bin` directory is not on the `PATH`, so you cannot find the server executable.

You'll have to modify the `PATH` environment variable appropriately.

Another possibility is that your `bash` was already running when you installed PostgreSQL, so that its `PATH` setting is out of date. Try closing `bash` and start a new one. Maybe that one has the correct setting.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the PATH environment variables. and it goes well.